# Out of bounds with find and replace in C++

Tags: c++

I seem to be running into an odd situation that I do not undersand in C++. When I execute a function that parses and replaces strings (Roman Numerals).  I end up going out of bound if the string is not present:

### Terminal output:

```
Mac Shell: CPP/>$ ./Roman2Num 

Retrieving input: 
------------------
Enter a number: 24
input: XXIV
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: basic_string
Abort trap: 6
Mac Shell: CPP/>$ ./Roman2Num 

Retrieving input: 
------------------
Enter a number: 29
input: XXVIV
Roman: XXIX 
Mac Shell: CPP/>$ ./Roman2Num 

Retrieving input: 
------------------
Enter a number: 1999
input: MDCDLXLVIV
Roman: MDCDLXLIX 
Mac Shell: CPP/>$ ./Roman2Num 

Retrieving input: 
------------------
Enter a number: 1998
input: MDCDLXLVIII
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: basic_string
Abort trap: 6
Mac Shell: CPP/>$
```

### Code written:

```
string Cleanup(string Roman){
    int count = 0;

    printf("input: %s\n", Roman.c_str());

    size_t w = Roman.find("VIV");
    Roman.replace(w, std::string("VIV").length(), "IX");


/*  size_t x = Roman.find("LIX");
    Roman.replace(x, std::string("LIX").length(), "IL");

    size_t y = Roman.find("VIV");
    Roman.replace(y, std::string("VIV").length(), "IX");

    size_t z = Roman.find("VIV");
    Roman.replace(z, std::string("VIV").length(), "IX");*/

    return Roman;
}
```

I have been doing some reading here:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/

- Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?
- Am I making this way harder than it needs to be?

Comment: If the string "VIV" is not found, what do you thing the value of `w` is?

Comment: I see that this goest to a 64-bit unsigned integer. Well I think that answers this question.  I will just have to do some logic here.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the string is not found `Romand.find()` returns `string::npos`, which equals `(std::string::size_type)-1`.

See here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/

Comment: Not actually "-1", since "size_t" cannot represent negative numbers.

Comment: size_t(-1) might be greater than unsigned(-1)

Comment: Niggly: replace `unsigned` with `size_type` and you can claim absolute correctness and moral superiority

Comment: @AJNeufeld Unsigned integer types in C and C++ can represent any integer, no matter how large or even negative, because they implement arithmetic mod 2^NumBit.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Yes, but `if (w >= 0)` won't protect against Not Found, because every `size_t` is non-negative.  Thinking of `npos` as `-1` will cause you grief.

Comment: @AJNeufeld This `if (w >= 0)` is one of the bigger reasons for why I'm not a big fan of using unsigned integer types for anything but bit magic. As this tends to spark nearly religious debates: [Here](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Interactive-Panel-Ask-Us-Anything) ( 9:50, 42:40, 1:02:50 ) the same message from the mouth of some C++ VIPs.

Comment: @BaummitAugen You're preaching to the choir :-)   But since `find` returns a `size_t`, and not a `signed`, and this question is about a bug due to not checking for the not found result, I think it is important to not confuse the issue with implicit type conversions, bit equivalency, and so on, and just use the API defined "not found" identifier.

Answer (score 5):

You need to check for and protect against the "Not Found" condition.

```
size_t w = Roman.find("VIV");
if (w != string::npos) {
    Roman.replace(w, string("VIV").length(), "IX");
}
```